# Remove empty line in a big string

Tags: c++, char, newline, carriage-return, blank-line

I would like to remove an empty line in a big string (not a file). 
This is the string :

```
The unique begin of a line in my string, after that a content same endline


        The unique begin of a line in my string, after that a content same endline
        The unique begin of a line in my string, after that a content same endline
```

This is how it appears on notepad++:

[image: Notepad]

Comment: You never initialize `OldCaractere`, `NumberReturnCaractere`, `NumberDoubleReturnCaractere` so they contain garbage.

Comment: Why wont you use strstr to find \n\n or something like that?

Comment: As you have this requirement can you change your design to be an `std::vector<std::string>>` or `std::list<std::string>>` where each element in the outer container is one line of the original text?

Comment: I can't change the design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution :**

```
string myString = "The string which contains double \r\n \r\n so it will be removed with this algorithm.";
int myIndex = 0;
while (myIndex < myString.length()) {
  if (myString[myIndex] == '\n') {
    myIndex++;
    while (myIndex < myString.length() && (myString[myIndex] == ' ' || myString[myIndex] == '\t' || myString[myIndex] == '\r' || myString[myIndex] == '\n')) {
      myString.erase(myIndex, 1);
    }
  } else {
    myIndex++;
  }
}
```

Comment: This code has several bugs in it: 1) comparison of signed and unsigned data types. 2) it removes not only empty lines, but also all whitespace characters from the beginning of the line following the empty one. 3) if you expect long strings with lot of empty lines, then you will have lot of `erase()` calls that move the string and thus your performance will suffer.

Answer (score 3):

Use regular expression. Following link to [regex reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/) should get you started. Or yet better [regex_replace](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_replace/).

Your regular expression will look like this

```
/\n\s*\n/
```

For regular expression tests might be helpful online [regex tester](https://regex101.com/).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main ()
{
  std::string s ("there is a line \n    \nanother line\n   \nand last one in the string\n");
  std::regex e ("\\n\\s*\\n");
  std::cout << std::regex_replace (s,e,"\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response, I don't understand how to use it in my case, can you give me a working code ?

Comment: See example in my  edited post. I have also changed reference to regex_replace instead of regex_search I used originally.